# Migrate service's volume from v2 to v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Below is an v2 `mongodata` volume based on `tianon/true` image:

```
version: "2" 
services:   
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes_from:
      - mongodata

  mongodata:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - /data/db
```

How to migrate it to a v3? My take below didn't work. Probably because this volume is not based to the image?

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Looks like you can't.

---

However you can copy the content:

- Identify all running volumes and names with: `docker system df -v`.
- Find which container is using a volume `docker ps -f "volume=VOLUMENAME"`
- Optionaly inpect it: `docker volume inspect VOLUMENAME`

---

When you identify which volume you like to copy, clone it:

```
docker run --rm \
           -i \
           -t \
           -v SOURCEVOLUME:/from \
           -v TARGETVOLUME:/to \
           alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"
```

[Clone script credits](https://github.com/gdiepen/docker-convenience-scripts/blob/master/docker_clone_volume.sh)

Comment: Yes, you can't - see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154 for a discussion. You'll also find an alternative for the manual `cp` by moving Docker's internal `_data` directory to the new volume: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154#issuecomment-334844525